# How to parse d character to different date format in R?

Tags: r, date, data.table, lubridate

I have a data table as

```
 V1                V2                V3
1: 3 09/09/17 21:31:23 09/09/17 21:31:23
2: 3 09/09/17 22:06:47 09/09/17 22:06:47
3: 3 09/09/17 22:14:29 09/09/17 22:18:17
```

from this I want to tranform it to

```
 V1                V2                V3
1: 3 2017-09-09 21:31:23 2017-09-09 21:31:23
2: 3 2017-09-09 22:06:47 2017-09-09 22:06:47
3: 3 2017-09-09 22:14:29 2017-09-09 22:18:17
```

The `V2` and `V3` columns are characters.

I tried by

```
DT[,V2:=parse_date_time2(V2,orders="YmdHMS",tz="NA")]
DT[,V3:=parse_date_time2(V3,orders="YmdHMS",tz="NA")]
DT[,V2:=strftime(V2, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"]
DT[,V3:=strftime(V3, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"]
```

But did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with `as.POSIXct` i.e. `DT[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'), .SDcols = 2:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wrong date time format is a very common error so I guess there must be a bunch of duplicate questions on SO.

However, The OP is asking for help for a combination of `data.table` and `lubridate`'s `parse_date_time2()` function. `parse_date_time2()` *is a fast C parser of numeric orders* according to `?parse_date_time2`.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

DT[, V2 := parse_date_time2(V2, orders = "mdyHMS")]
DT[, V3 := parse_date_time2(V3, orders = "mdyHMS")]
DT
```

> ```
>       V1                  V2                  V3
>    <int>              <POSc>              <POSc>
> 1:     3 2017-09-09 21:31:23 2017-09-09 21:31:23
> 2:     3 2017-09-09 22:06:47 2017-09-09 22:06:47
> 3:     3 2017-09-09 22:14:29 2017-09-09 22:18:17
> ```

The presumably correct format string `"mdyHMS"` is passed to `orders` while the OP used `"YmdHMS"`. (Perhaps, the OP has specified the order of date formats in the desired output but not as they appear in the input?)

I say *presumably* correct format string because the date string `09/09/17` is ambiguous without additional information. The string can be interpreted as `mdy`, `dmy`, `ymd`, or `myd`.

The whole operation can be coded more concisely as

```
cols = c("V2", "V3")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, mdy_hms), .SDcols = cols]
```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
3, 09/09/17 21:31:23, 09/09/17 21:31:23
3, 09/09/17 22:06:47, 09/09/17 22:06:47
3, 09/09/17 22:14:29, 09/09/17 22:18:17")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(2:3, dmy_hms)

    # A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1                  V2                  V3
  <chr>              <dttm>              <dttm>
1  1: 3 2017-09-09 21:31:23 2017-09-09 21:31:23
2  2: 3 2017-09-09 22:06:47 2017-09-09 22:06:47
3  3: 3 2017-09-09 22:14:29 2017-09-09 22:18:17
```